# Display on MacBook Pro 13 (Mid 2014) dead after installing Ubuntu 18.04. Works on HDMI when lid is closed

Tags: macos, laptop, hardware-failure, uefi

I have a MacBook Pro 13 Retina (Mid 2014) and the screen has gone off and never comes back  on again. It happend after installed Ubuntu 18.04 and refit.

At end of install I observe diverse graphic errors and force power off the computer (holding power button for 5 sec).

If the computer keep closed it works on external display over HDMI but not on it’s own display.

Anyone can help me?

**UPDATE**: The laptop continues with black screen problem, I try different method to try resolve this but none works.

I try this:

- Reset SMC
- Reset PRAM
- Reinstall OSX
- Recovery from Internet
- Reflash SMC with this command:

  ```
  sudo /usr/sbin/bless -mount / -firmware ~/Desktop/MBPRetinaEFIUpdate-1.3/MBP111_0138_B03_LOCKED.scap --recovery --setBoot --nextonly --verbose
  ```

Open the case and disconnected battery cable, SSH and display.

And none of these work, the laptop only works on external display. But if I try open the display nothing happens.

I don't know what's the problem but seems resolution parameters of the integrated display, Ubuntu installer must be change this on firmware (it's possible?)

**SOLUTION**
After testing all the tests and solutions that I know, I disassembled the computer (motherboard, fans, etc.) and stored it in its own case for almost six months. After that I reassembled the laptop and now it's fine. It seems that after these months anything has restarted because it's had no power and this must be had "repaired" the computer.

Comment: It could be the install failed to install proper drivers for the internal display. Or the resolution Ubuntu is setting is out of the range of the internal display. I would recommend booting it up connected to HDMI, then open the lid of the MacBook Pro and then play with display settings.

Comment: thanks for you quickly reply. The laptop continues with black screen problem, I try different method to try resolve this but none works

Comment: Hello again, today I write this message from my old MacBook. Last summer, I am was trying to solve the problem of all the methods I know (reset the system, repair the boot, change the boot configuration and others). The last thing I did was disassemble the laptop and store it in its box in pieces for about six months. and last week I was assembly it again  and  now it's  works. I don't know if I was clearly was happens, but I try because I read several pages. The problem was solved by disconnecting the battery, but for me it doesn't work.

Comment: If you've solved the issue then it is fine to post as an answer that address the original question. In this case you can copy your own comment and post as the solution